# SELECT DISTINCT queries between two columns that matches either values

Tags: sql, sqlite, fmdb

I have following tables:

TABLE_A

```
|      some_id      | entity_id| tableB_id| position |
|-------------------|----------|----------|----------|
|         388       |     8    |    5783  |    0     |
|         389       |     8    |    776   |    1     |
|         390       |     8    |    5765  |    2     |
|         391       |     8    |    5743  |    3     |
|         392       |     8    |    6167  |    4     |
|         393       |     8    |    6168  |    5     |
|         394       |     8    |    6169  |    6     |
|         708       |     11   |    501   |    3     |
```

TABLE_B

```
|     some_id       |  key_1  |     key2      | tableC_id |isSomeCheck|isOtherCheck|
|-------------------|---------|-------------- |-----------|-----------|------------|
|     776           | null    |   pqrstuvw1234|    311    |    1      |     0      |
|    5743           | sfrwt0  |   sofdsfsdr456|    1829   |    1      |     0      |
|    5765           | null    |   abcdefgh4567|    321    |    1      |     0      |
|    5783           | null    |   something341|    1841   |    1      |     0      |
|    6167           | somer9  |   null        |    1956   |    0      |     0      |
|    6168           | richt6  |   null        |    1957   |    0      |     0      |
|    6169           | done60  |   null        |    1957   |    0      |     0      |
```

TABLE_C

```
|     some_id       |  key_1   | sortName |
|-------------------|----------|----------|
|       311         |  tes456  |    WWW   |
|       321         |  don890  |    UNK   |
|      1829         |  som123  |    ILA   |
|      1841         |  ken980  |    ARI   |
|      1956         |  lam123  |    KOR   |
|      1957         |  kes648  |    ERO   |
```

Either `isSomeCheck` or `isOtherCheck` must be 1.

Current query that I am running returns results where only key_1 in TABLE_B is present:

```
SELECT  TABLE_A.some_id FROM TABLE_B
    JOIN TABLE_A
        ON TABLE_A.tableB_id = TABLE_B.some_id
    JOIN     (SELECT tableB.some_id AS tableBID,
            tableC.sortName  AS tableCSortName
     FROM   TABLE_B AS tableB
            INNER JOIN TABLE_C AS tableC
                    ON tableB.tableC_id = tableC.some_id
     GROUP  BY tableB.some_id)
        ON TABLE_A.tableB_id = tableBID WHERE TABLE_B.key_1 in (select distinct(key_1) from TABLE_B where key_1 = TABLE_B.key_1 and TABLE_B.isRequired = 1 or TABLE_B.isChecked = 1) AND entity_id = 8  ORDER BY TABLE_A.position
```

Outputs:

```
|      some_id      |
|-------------------|
|         391       |
```

Everything works fine, except I also want to have `some_id` from TABLE_A if key_1 is absent from TABLE_B and key_2 is present like an OR condition. Basically, I also want to consider key_2 in the output.

So, my expected output would look like:

```
|      some_id      |
|-------------------|
|         388       |
|         389       |
|         390       |
|         391       |
```

**What I tried and returns *correct* output:**

```
SELECT  TABLE_A.some_id FROM TABLE_B
    JOIN TABLE_A
        ON TABLE_A.tableB_id = TABLE_B.some_id
    JOIN     (SELECT tableB.some_id AS tableBID,
            tableC.sortName  AS tableCSortName
     FROM   TABLE_B AS tableB
            INNER JOIN TABLE_C AS tableC
                    ON tableB.tableC_id = tableC.some_id
     GROUP  BY tableB.some_id)
        ON TABLE_A.tableB_id = tableBID
        WHERE 
        (TABLE_B.key_2 in (select distinct(key_2) from TABLE_B where key_2 = TABLE_B.key_2 and TABLE_B.isSomeCheck = 1 or TABLE_B.isOtherCheck = 1) or
        TABLE_B.key_1 in (select distinct(key_1) from TABLE_B where key_1 = TABLE_B.key_1 and TABLE_B.isSomeCheck = 1 or TABLE_B.isOtherCheck = 1))
        AND entity_id = 8  ORDER BY TABLE_A.position;
```

Is this the right way of achieving the output I need or is there any better way to achieve this so that I can update `WHERE` clause in the above query?

I would have liked to remove the duplicated code that checks isSomeCheck and isOtherCheck in both of the select distinct query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a sub-query to check the values of TABLE_B columns, you already joined this table and you could access its columns directly, so your first query could be written as the following:

```
SELECT  tbl_a.some_id 
FROM TABLE_B tbl_B JOIN TABLE_A tbl_a
ON tbl_a.tableB_id = tbl_b.some_id
JOIN   TABLE_C tbl_c
ON tbl_b.tableC_id = tbl_c.some_id 
WHERE tbl_a.entity_id = 8 AND
      (tbl_b.isSomeCheck = 1 OR tbl_b.isOtherCheck = 1) AND
      tbl_b.key_1 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY tbl_a.position
```

The use of `tbl_b.key_1 IS NOT NULL` condition is to check the presence of `key_1` in table_b, here we could use the `coalesce` function to check the presence of *key_1 or key_2* in table_b. The `coalesce` function will return the first not null value, so your second query could be written as the following:

```
SELECT  tbl_a.some_id 
FROM TABLE_B tbl_B JOIN TABLE_A tbl_a
ON tbl_a.tableB_id = tbl_b.some_id
JOIN   TABLE_C tbl_c
ON tbl_b.tableC_id = tbl_c.some_id 
WHERE tbl_a.entity_id = 8 AND
      (tbl_b.isSomeCheck = 1 OR tbl_b.isOtherCheck = 1) AND
      COALESCE(tbl_b.key_1, tbl_b.key2) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY tbl_a.position
```

[see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LfEnFfkY)